# How to sync a PHP project using RSync and NetBeans?

Tags: php, netbeans, ssh, rsync

I just installed the lastest version of Netbeans (7.2).

I would like to sync my project with a remote server using rsync (or another ssh based tool).

I tried to search for the plugin but I did not find it.

Could someone help me?

Comment: I'd look at a deployment tool like Capistrano or Ant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Ant, you can add a `build.ant` file into your project. Right-clicking on the file should give you a *"Run Target"* option where you can run your ant tasks.

Here's an example `build.ant` file with a *deploy* task

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Project Name" default="deploy">
    <property name="username" value="username"/>
    <property name="host" value="example.com"/>
    <property name="path" value="/path/to/project/dir"/>

    <target name="deploy">
        <exec dir="." executable="rsync" failonerror="true">
            <arg value="-avu"/>
            <arg value="."/>
            <arg value="${username}@${host}:${path}"/>
        </exec>
    </target>
</project>
```

Capistrano is probably a better option but I'm not sure about the integration with NetBeans

Comment: thank you, but I log into the server using keys how could i set the key's path(the private key i have in my pc) in this XML to let Ant uses that key during the login on the server?