# Deploy ANT file in netbeans from macro

Tags: netbeans, macros, ant

[How to sync a PHP project using RSync and NetBeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545945/how-to-sync-a-php-project-using-rsync-and-netbeans)

The above link @Phil showed me how to write an ANT file which in turn runs a command to rsync a project from point a to point b.

Although this is great, I am struggling to figure out how to trigger this via a macro in netbeans. It seems when i record the macro, it is not picking up right clicks...

I have been getting used to netbeans bit by bit, moving from komodo edit, but this last hurdle is meaning i am still reliant on komodo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My work around was this:

1 - create the ant file

2 - when starting the project for the day, run the default target

3 - for the rest of the day (or until i need to use a different target) use the keyboard short cut to running the ant file:  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>